# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()',

Tags: pandas, apply

when I use pandas.DataFrame.apply,it shows "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,2))

def fun(df):
    median=df.median()
    mad=(df-median).median()
    if df>(median+3.1483*mad):
        df=median+3.1483*mad
    elif df<(median-3.1483*mad):
        df=median-3.1483*mad
    return df
df.apply(fun)
```

Comment: Inside your function, `df` is a `pd.Series`. So, `df>(median+3.1483*mad)` yields something like `if pd.Series([True, False, False, True, etc])` which doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: Hmmm, is `mad=(df-median).median()` correct?

Comment: OK, I have corrected it,even though I do not know whether it is true                          df[median+3*mad]=median+3*mad     df[median-3*mad]=median-3*mad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
def fun(df):
    median=df.median()
    mad=(df-median).median()
    m1 = df>(median+3.1483*mad)
    df= df.mask(m1, median+3.1483*mad)
    m2 = df<(median-3.1483*mad)
    df=df.mask(m2, median-3.1483*mad)
    return df
df3 = df.apply(fun)
```

Another solution, but because `mad` is close `0` then `3.1483*mad` and `-3.1483*mad` is zero too, so get output of means `df.median()` in both columns:

```
np.random.seed(786)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2))
print (df)
          0         1
0 -0.799307  1.065501
1 -0.246459  0.856806
2 -1.505766 -1.071535
3 -0.027080  0.707278
4 -1.946180  0.653074
5  0.093481 -1.825020
6  1.990691  0.811006
7  2.367850 -0.388028
8 -2.174134 -1.161844
9 -0.279455  0.082329
```

---

```
median=df.median()
print (median)
0   -0.262957
1    0.367702
dtype: float64

mad=(df-median).median()
print (mad)
0    1.387779e-17
1   -2.775558e-17
dtype: float64
```

---

```
m1 = df.gt((median+3.1483*mad), axis=1)
m2 = df.lt((median-3.1483*mad), axis=1)
print (m1)
       0      1
0  False   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
4  False   True
5   True  False
6   True   True
7   True  False
8  False  False
9  False  False

print (m2)
       0      1
0   True  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
3  False  False
4   True  False
5  False   True
6  False  False
7  False   True
8   True   True
9   True   True
```

---

```
s1 = median+3.1483*mad #like s1 = median
s2 = median-3.1483*mad #like s2 = median
print (s2)
0   -0.262957
1    0.367702
dtype: float64
print (s1)
0   -0.262957
1    0.367702
dtype: float64

df3 = df.mask(m1, s1, axis=1).mask(m2, s2, axis=1)
print (df3)
          0         1
0 -0.262957  0.367702
1 -0.262957  0.367702
2 -0.262957  0.367702
3 -0.262957  0.367702
4 -0.262957  0.367702
5 -0.262957  0.367702
6 -0.262957  0.367702
7 -0.262957  0.367702
8 -0.262957  0.367702
9 -0.262957  0.367702
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer. I have thought it over for long time. Because of your help,I found  the way to resolve it.